# Entity Framework Function Import problem

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, mapping

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 with POCO. I add some entities from database, then i rename entity properties.
  For example i have table "Person" with fields **ID, Name**. I rename my entity "Person" so:

**ID -> PR_ID,**

**Name -> PR_Name**.

Then i create stored procedure:

```
select * from Person
```

Then i create function import based on this sp, and specify Entity "Person" as return type.
When this function import occurs at run-time i get exception:

```
{"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Model.Person'. 
A member of the type, 'PR_ID', does not have a corresponding column 
in the data reader with the same name."}
```

*here is my questions:*

1. If there is mapping for "Person" entity, which tells **convert ID to PR_ID** and **convert Name to PR_Name**, why my function import doesn`t use this mapping?
2. I can specify aliases for each column in sp, like:

> ```
> select ID as PR_ID, Name as PR_Name from Person
> ```

but is there other solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column names in the stored procedure. If you don't there is no way for the function import to infer the mapping.